# Restrict download to Macbook / MacOS of published mobile iOS App

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, app-store

We recently had released the app on `App Store for iPhone and iPad but once the app got published we do see the Mac OS support and we are even able to download the app in our` Macboox`and`iMac`.

Is there a way to restrict this or apple does do this automatically as we haven't configured anything for Mac OS?

[image]

Comment: It is explained in [this page](https://developer.apple.com/macos/iphone-and-ipad-apps/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of M1 Macs is that they run iPad apps natively. OK, maybe not the *whole* point, but it's a major part of the meaning of an M1 Mac: its processor is an iPad processor so its apps can be iPad apps.

If you don't want *your* iPad app to be downloaded to an M1 Mac, you need to opt out. You can do that on the Pricing and Availability page of your app's entry on App Store Connect:

[image]

Note the checkbox. It is *checked by default*. Unchecking it is up to *you*. You didn't uncheck it, so your app was downloaded to some M1 Macs.